# Cannot use $http service from different domain

Tags: angularjs

I get this error

```
Failed to load resource: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the 
requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. 
http://hiddenadress.com/index.php

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://hiddenadress.com/index.php.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

when I try to use this function from localhost

```
$http.post('http://hidden.com/server/index.php', {
  "query": "SELECT * FROM n08_minMax"
}).success(function(data, status) {
    $scope.minPrice = $scope.priceStart = data[0].N08_min;
    $scope.maxPrice = $scope.priceEnd = data[0].N08_max;
  }).error(function(data, status) {
    $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
    $scope.status = status;
  });
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: hidden.com needs to set the appropriate CORS (cross origin resource sharing) headers to allow other domains to GET/POST to it. The headers are Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, etc. Hopefully this will set you on the right track.

Comment: I added 

`header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");`

but now I get

`OPTIONS http://hidden.com/server/index.php Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. angular.js:7883
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://hidden.com/server/index.php. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. `

Comment: try: header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');`. Also, you're adding this to the hidden.com server's headers, not localhost, right?

Comment: Yes, I add this to hidden.com server headers. Well, still doesnt work, I get the same error. Maybe I need to set smth in client side?

Comment: I missed this in your error msg: "...is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers" so try `header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *')`

Comment: You cant use wild card in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers:`. But you comments got me on the right way and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, accept` did the job. Thank you :)